# Find the basis of some direct complement of the subspace $M$ in vector space $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $M=\{p \in P_3 : p(2)=0$ and $ p(1-x)=p(1+x)\}$. Find the basis of some direct complement of the subspace $M$ in vector space $P_3$.

In order to do this, I first have to find the basis for $M$. But how do I that?

This is what I did:

$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

$p(2)=8a+4b+2c+d=0$ $\Rightarrow p(x)=a(x^3-8)+b(x^2-4)+c(x-2)$

Then  $p(1-x)=a(-x^3+3x^2-3x-7)+b(x^2-2x-3)+c(-1-x)$ and $p(1+x)=a(x^3+3x^2+3x-7)+b(x^2+2x-3)+c(x-1)$

If $p(1-x)=p(1+x)$ then

$-x^3+3x^2-3x-7=x^3+3x^2+3x-7$,

$x^2-2x-3=x^2+2x-3$ and

$-1-x=x-1$

From this I get $x=0$, but I still don't understand how to find the basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do some polynomial arithmetic first:

- $p(2)=0$, hence $p(x)$ is divisible by $x-2$;
- $p(1-x)=p(1+x)$, hence setting $x=1$, you have $p(1)=p(2)=0$, so $p(x)$ is also divisible  by $x$. We conclude that
  $$(x)=x(x-2)(ax+b)\quad (a,b\in\mathbf R)$$
  The second condition becomes
  $$-(1-x)(1+x)(a+b-ax)=(1+x)(-1+x)(a+b-ax)\iff a=0.$$

Thus $ M$ is the $1$-dimensional subspace $\;\langle\, x(x-2)\,\rangle$.

There remains to find a set of $3$ linearly independent polynomial which, together with $p(x)$, generate $\mathbf R_3$. As this space has dimension $4$, we know a set of $4$ generators is a basis. The set $\{\, 1,x,x^3\,\}$ is an obvious candidate.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$
0 = p(1 + x) - p(1 - x) = ax^3 + (3a + 2b + c)x,
$$

which is true iff $a = 0$ and $2b + c = 0$. Thus,

$$
p(x) = b(x^2 - 2x).
$$